# Eclipse cannot find the main class in JFace?

Tags: java, eclipse, jface

I'm working though a book SWT/JFace IN ACTION by Manning Press.

When I added JFace,  Eclipse for some reason could not find the main class though it is plainly present.

Here is the code

```
package com.swtjface.ChTwo;

import org.eclipse.jface.window.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class HelloSWT_JFace extends ApplicationWindow{

/**
 * @param args
 */
public HelloSWT_JFace(){
    super(null);
}
protected Control createContents(Composite parent){
    Text helloText = new Text(parent, SWT.CENTER);
    helloText.setText("Hello SWT and JFace!");
    parent.pack();
    return parent;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HelloSWT_JFace awin = new HelloSWT_JFace();
    awin.setBlockOnOpen(true);
    awin.open();
    Display.getCurrent().dispose();
}

 }
```

The reject message I get from Eclipse is...

```
Could not find the main class: com.swtjface.ChTwo.HelloSWT_JFace.
Program will exit.
```

Here is the exception...

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least 2 more jars to use JFace:

- org.eclipse.equinox.common
- org.eclipse.core.commands

See [Using JFace outside the Eclipse platform](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace#Using_JFace_outside_the_Eclipse_platform) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add jar file for "org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor class"

Check [this link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/DEF/Downloadeclipsejar.htm).